# Makefile rule error: *** mixed implicit and normal rules

Tags: makefile

in kernel Makefile

```
# Modules                                                                                                                                                                               
/ %/: prepare scripts FORCE
    $(cmd_crmodverdir)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) \
    $(build)=$(build-dir)
%.ko: prepare scripts FORCE
    $(cmd_crmodverdir)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1)   \
    $(build)=$(build-dir) $(@:.ko=.o)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.modpost
```

causing error **Makefile mixed implicit and normal rules.** (to first string on provided code)

I think something wrong with **/ %/** syntax, how can I repair it?

so far I'm thinking about separating rules this way:

```
# Modules                                                                                                                                                                               
/: prepare scripts FORCE
    $(cmd_crmodverdir)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) \
    $(build)=$(build-dir)
%/: prepare scripts FORCE
    $(cmd_crmodverdir)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) \
    $(build)=$(build-dir)
%.ko: prepare scripts FORCE
    $(cmd_crmodverdir)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1)   \
    $(build)=$(build-dir) $(@:.ko=.o)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.modpost
```

But it's confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think the `/ %/` rule is doing (apart from confuse you and `make` -- and me)?  What are you trying to achieve with the `%/` bit?

You can have two (or more) targets on the left of the colon, but they both need to be percent-less.

```
prog1 prog2: something
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.o ${LIBRARIES}
```

The `%` metacharacter cannot be used with a rule without any `%` in it, but `make` is interpreting:

```
/ %/:
```

as similar to the `prog1 prog2` example, but one of the targets has a `%` and the other does not, and you're not allowed to mix these up.  The `/` rule is the explicit rule; it appears to be instructions on how to update the root directory of your system.  The `%/` is the implicit rule; it might be doing something related to making directories up to date.

---

Copying some material up from the comments:

```
DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES = \
    $(cmd_crmodverdir); \
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) $(build)=$(build-dir)

/:  prepare scripts FORCE; $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)

%/: prepare scripts FORCE; $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)
```

This notation should work (which is why I used it in the comment), but what I'd write in a `makefile` is:

```
DIRECTORY_DEPENDENCIES = prepare scripts FORCE
DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES = \
    $(cmd_crmodverdir); \
    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) $(build)=$(build-dir)

/:  $(DIRECTORY_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)

%/: $(DIRECTORY_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)
```

If this still causes trouble, review what the first (the `/:`) rule does.  Are you sure it is needed?

Comment: Good but is my solution there correct? As far as I understand I need to separate it this way but running same make 2 times is looking like strange for me.

Comment: Yes; the separation will be necessary.  Yes, writing out the same rules twice is not great.  Maybe create a macro for the actions, and then use that in the rules.  `DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES = $(cmd_crmodverdir); $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) $(build)=$(build-dir)`, then: `/: prepare scripts FORCE; $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)` and `%s: prepare scripts FORCE; $(DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES)`.  You could even make the dependency list into another macro...

Comment: now it tells : Recursive variable `DIRECTORY_BUILD_RULES' references itself (eventually).  Stop.

Comment: Are you sure you need the 'plain `/` rule'?  Does the `%/` rule cover it too?  I don't see how the macro depends on itself...what I wrote did not.  It might depend on what the `$(if ...)` function does, I suppose.