# Error: mixed implicit and normal rules

Tags: makefile, kernel-module

I have just updated `make` to

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

and before hand this make file worked

```
MODULE_NAME = module
$(MODULE_NAME)-objs := Charset.o Connector.o Fpga.o FpgaBus.o FpgaFlash.o I2c.o Key.o Module.o \
                   Oled.o PhoneAudio.o Splash.o AudioCodecIO.o Connection.o Server.o
EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I./include2 -I./include -DALLOW_LOWER_CASE

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

obj-m := $(MODULE_NAME).o

else

KDIR := ./build/
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-softfloat-linux-uclibceabi- $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-softfloat-linux-uclibceabi- $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

install:
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-softfloat-linux-uclibceabi- $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

endif
```

now it does not with this error

```
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-softfloat-linux-uclibceabi- make -C ./build/ M=/home/liam/Dev/driver modules
Makefile:23: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shared/firmware/atmel/kernel'
make: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shared/firmware/atmel/kernel'
```

Any idea what is causing this issue?

EDIT:

Ok, i have more info now. An auto generated Makefile is pulled in from the `./build/` directory and looks like this.

```
# Automatically generated by /home/shared/firmware/src/linux/scripts/mkmakefile: don't edit

VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6

lastword = $(word $(words $(1)),$(1))
makedir := $(dir $(call lastword,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

MAKEARGS := -C /home/shared/firmware/src/linux
MAKEARGS += O=$(if $(patsubst /%,,$(makedir)),$(CURDIR)/)$(patsubst %/,%,$(makedir))

MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory

.PHONY: all $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all := $(filter-out all Makefile,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

all:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEARGS) $(all)

Makefile:;

$(all) %/: all
   @:
```

Looking at it and looking at other posts, this may now be a duplicate question. the last few lines should not be this with this version of `make`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make error of mixed implicit and normal rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945091/make-error-of-mixed-implicit-and-normal-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is changing the kernel build generated `Makefile` lines

From:

```
$(all) %/: all
   @:
```

To:

```
$(all) : all
```

There are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356966/655703) that can explain the reasons behind this better then I can.